# Amazon S3 and DynamoDB

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, database-connection, amazon-dynamodb

I have a question that keeps playing in my mind. The question is...
Is there any possibility to connect database in DynamoDB with file in Amazon S3?

What I mean is, I have the details about files(.pdf) like the title, author, year of publication in DynamoDB, and the files are in bucket of Amazon S3. So, is there any possibility for me to connect these 2 services using JAVA ANDROID?

I tried to search but it seems that the more i seek for it, the more i get confused.

Anyone may help? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. It's call [S3Link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/mobileconnectors/dynamodbv2/dynamodbmapper/S3Link.html). Check out this blog post [Using S3Link with Amazon DynamoDB](https://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx3V3QS57D88QCR/Using-S3Link-with-Amazon-DynamoDB).

Comment: thank you!! I will have a look onto this. TQ once again!

Comment: I dont understand about DynamoMapper mapper = new DynamoMapper(awscrdentialsprovider, s3provider);

awscrdentialsprovider and s3provider, what are the differences?

Comment: I don't see that constructor. I believe it allows you to use different credentials providers to create one DynamoDB client and one S3 client for the mapper.